On the fly video conversion in django during upload
I an making a backend in django rest where user will be uploading videos in multiple formats such as mp4, avi, etc. I want to convert these videos to a single h264 format while storing them but rather than first taking the full video and then converting it i want to convert it while it is being uploaded how can i do that.
The video file is comming through multipart/form-data
I have been stucck and not able to find a plausible approach but i know that i have to use FFMpeg in some manner.

why not just receive the file completely and then process it? what you want is more complicated. if you knew how to do it, that'd be fine, but you're asking others to solve that for you, without showing your own research or attempt.

Processing video in main django request - response cycle would be a bad aida.(only good in a local environment, for testing) It should be done by background task processes. Like, using something like dramatiq(support windows), celery(no windows support).

@Illucious  (1) Be aware that some MP4 keep their metadata at back of file, so FFmpeg cannot convert such MP4 until they are fully uploaded. (2) The only way to do on-the-fly would be to use std in/out to manually send chunks (into FFmpeg) that are sliced from the user file (eg: each one is a 64kb chunk)... I don't know if Django is the right server-side language, but PHP could do it.

It is recommended that you use a streaming protocol such as RTMP or HLS to receive streams.
